# Spring doesn't find a bean for view

Tags: spring

I have a controller which maps the path `/` to a file `index.html`.

I am getting an error that normally doesn't show up in the log, but when debug logging is turned on then it shows:

```
No matching bean found for view name 'index'
```

This is probably a trivial error but I couldn't find anything on it. Mostly I found questions like `No matching bean of type ... found for dependency ...` but I don't think they are the same as this one.

PS. This may be unrelated but if I write code like this:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("title", "My custom title");
    return "index";
}
```

I don't see any change in the title.

Comment: Do you have ViewResolvers configured for your application ? Provide your DispatcherServlet application context configuration

Comment: It isn't an error it is a debug/trace messages telling you that a particular `ViewResolver` (probably the `BeanNameViewResolver`) cannot find a bean. It is a debug message NOT an error...

Comment: @M.Deinum Do I need to do anything, and are the two issues related?

Comment: @ekemchitsiga `DispatcherServlet application context configuration` where do I find it?

Comment: No it isn't an issue... It is just an information message...

Comment: An xml file containing "<bean/>" elements or a Java class containg @Bean methods

Comment: @ekemchitsiga No such file. I don't have any `.xml` files in my project, apart from `logback`.